# Android RadioGroup button gravity

Tags: android, xml, radio-button, gravity, radio-group

As i was developing an app and i needed radio buttons, i decided to create a `RadioGroup` and inside it, i created 3 `RadioButton`s and i wanted to position them to the left, center, and right accordingly.

I put `android:orientation:"horizontal"` in `RadioGroup` and i have placed `android:layout_gravity="left` right or center in `RadioButton`s created inside RadioGroup, but it just places the buttons next to each other aligned left, and distorts the text a little bit.

Same thing happens if i apply `android:gravity="left"` to the buttons.

I am not sure how to align first button on the left side, second on the center, and third on the right side.

Thanks!

Comment: post your whole layout.xml file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this in your layout :

```
<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="3"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="1"/>
    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="2"/>
    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="3"/>
    </RadioGroup>
```